# Change color line under autocomplete editext (Android)

Tags: android, colors, android-edittext

I'm using an `AutoCompleteEditText` and some `EditText`. I have edited the color of the line under the `EditText` and it works but when I attempt to change the color of line under the `AutoCompleteEditText`, the color remains green. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Thanks but I resolved it with http://android-holo-colors.com/

Comment: Good to hear . Happy coding